# Reading a table with only one scanf

Tags: c

This code with C language is supposed to count all characters equal to A as well as number characters in a table .. ~~ I've started by reading the table's characters giving by the user using a for loop and then i've used another for loop to count the number of characters equal to A as well as numbers~~
THE PROBLEM is with SCANF! what should I do to write scanf one time and not twice ???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char T[100] = {0};
                        
    int i=0,N=0,b=0,n=0,x=0,j=0,k=0;
    
    printf("give the number of your table's columns  \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    if (N > 0 && N <= 100) {
        for (i; i < N; i++) {
            
            scanf("%c",T[i]);
            printf("give the character of the column number  %d /n", i);
            scanf("%c",T[i]);
        }
      
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          
            if (T[i] == 'A') b++; 
               else if (T[i]<='9' && T[i]>='0') n++;
        }
         printf("the number of characters equal to A is  %d\n",b);
         printf("The number of numeric characters is %d\n",n);
        
   
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obtain user input with `fgets()`. Forget `scanf()`.

Comment: Can u please show me how can I use fgets()? I've never used it

Comment: Tip: Declare your variables where they're first used, don't heap up the definitions at the tip. Example: `for (int i = 0; ...)` instead of pre-declaring `i`. This helps avoid a lot of junk building up, like here there's a bunch of variables not even used.

Comment: Also: `/n` should probably be `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
                        
    int i, A_bin=0, Num_bin=0,length;
    char array[100];
    
    printf("Enter a string of numbers and letters: ");
    scanf("%s",array); //Storing the Char array in "array"
    length=strlen(array); //Getting the length of the Char array
    
    for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
    {
        if (array[i]=='A') A_bin+=1;
        else if (array[i]>= '0' && array[i]<='9') Num_bin+=1;
    }   
   
    printf("The amount of 'A's in the string is: %d \n" ,A_bin);
    printf("The amount of digits in the string is: %d" ,Num_bin);
   
        return 0;
}
```

Instead of that story I wrote you. Here is what I think you were looking for right. This only looks for capital 'A' although could be adjusted for any characters you wanted by following the scheme. You could always adjust the array size as well for very large inputs. May have errors, play with it and see how it works. Hope the example I provided helped.

Output Example:

```
Enter a string of numbers and letters: AAJUR874EYRIAA                                                                                          
The amount of 'A's in the string is: 4                                                                                                         
The amount of digits in the string is: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

your code needing only few editing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char T[100]={0};
                        
    int i=0,N=0,b=0,n=0,x=0,j=0,k=0;
    
    printf("give the number of your table's columns:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &N);
    if (N > 0 && N <= 100) 
    {
        for (i=0; i < N; i++) {
            //one scanf removed
        printf("give the character of the column number  %d \n", i);//<--/n to \n
        scanf(" %c",&T[i]); //<-- & added to store the value
        }
      
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          
            if (T[i] == 'A') b++; 
               else if (T[i]<='9' && T[i]>='0') n++;
        }
         printf("the number of characters equal to A is  %d\n",b);
         printf("The number of numeric characters is %d\n",n);
        
   
    }
        return 0;
}
```

while using scanf use `&` so it can store value while using scanf give a space before the `scanf(" %c",&T[i]);`

```
for (i; i < N; i++) {
            
            scanf("%c",T[i]);
            printf("give the character of the column number  %d /n", i);
            scanf("%c",T[i]);
        }
```

here you tried to override T[i] twice without `&` in scanf removing one `scanf` and adding `&` and also `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` will be better way to go use `\n` instead of `/n`